# Is 1.4mm Pad Distance at Optocoupler Pins for 230V/50Hz Mains Detector Enough?

Tags: pcb, mains, opto-isolator, insulation

For a project, I use an optocoupler to detect 230V/50Hz AC on a line - if a light switch connected to mains is pressed.

[image]

For my calculation, I use 240V as a maximum AC voltage. It will limit the current to 1.2mA for the LEDs of the optocoupler.

My board has a minimum trace distance of 3mm for all traces, except the distance of the pads between the optocoupler:

[image]

The shown distance (yellow) is 1.4mm.

**I assume, there is only a voltage of 1.4V across these pins, therefore the distance would be enough. Is this correct?**

Comment: Why do you care about clearance between these 2 pads? They are both on the HVAC side, and are connected with diodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is only about 1.2V peak between the pins, what you need to worry about is creepage across the isolation barrier.

Comment: So, adding an air gap between these pins would put me on the safe side?

Comment: Between input and output, yes it would be better, but only you know the requirements of your application. For many purposes 8mm creepage is adequate.

Comment: 8mm between the traces? Do you mean the 3mm distance between my traces is to narrow? The PCB will be sealed in a case, so there is no risk of dust or dirt.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I understand. There is a 4mm air gap routed under the optocoupler.